# populate list items from shared preferences data

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I am now trying to send data from `ListActivity` to another `ListActivity` by using `SharedPreferences`. I added data in `OnItemClickListener` with `SharedPreferences`. I have no idea how to populate data in another `ListActivity` using `ArrayList`. Below is the codes.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.SHARED_PRED, 0);
            Editor edit = pref.edit();

            edit.putString("TITLE", getItem(position).title);
            edit.putString("CHAR", getItem(position).character);
            edit.putString("TOTAL", getItem(position).totalpages+"");
            edit.putString("THUMB", getItem(position).thumbnail);
            edit.putInt("CODE", getItem(position).code);
            edit.commit();

            System.out.println("Title >>>>>>" + getItem(position).title);
            System.out.println("Character >>>>>>" + getItem(position).character);
            System.out.println("Total >>>>>>" + getItem(position).totalpages);
            System.out.println("thumb url >>>>>>" + getItem(position).thumbnail);
            System.out.println("Code >>>>>>" + getItem(position).code);

            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), DetailPager.class);
            i.putExtra("NPOS", position);
            getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

My scenario is that i have two activity in my application. First Activity will launch `ListActivity` by using `SharedPreferences`. Second Activity will load `DetailPager.class` which is written in codes. My problem is that i don't know how to populate `ListActivity` which is not launch in `OnClick` event.

**My ListActivity Class**

```
private ListViewAdapter m_adapter;
public ArrayList<String> cat = new ArrayList<String>();
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String title, character, thumbnail, totalPages;
int Code;

TextView titleView, charView, totalView;
ImageView thumbView, removeView;
Uri thumbUri;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.myputet);
    init_UI();
}

public void init_UI() {
    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.SHARED_PRED, 0);
    editor = preferences.edit();

    title = preferences.getString("TITLE", "");
    character = preferences.getString("CHAR", "");
    thumbnail = preferences.getString("THUMB", "");
    thumbUri = Uri.parse(thumbnail);
    totalPages = preferences.getString("TOTAL", "");
    Code = preferences.getInt("CODE", 0);

    System.out.println("Getting Title " + title);
    System.out.println("Getting character " + character);
    System.out.println("Getting thumbnail " + thumbnail);
    System.out.println("Getting thumbUri " + thumbUri);
    System.out.println("Getting totalPages " + totalPages);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    m_adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.myputet_item, cat);
    lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
}

private class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myputet_item, null);
        }
        String info = items.get(position);

        if (info != null) {
            titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxtView);
            charView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.charTxtView);
            totalView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.totalTxtView);
            thumbView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.charImageView);
            removeView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.removeListItem);

            titleView.setText(title);
            charView.setText(character);
            totalView.setText(totalPages);
            thumbView.setImageURI(thumbUri);
        }
        return v;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Why don't you serialize what getItem(position) returns and do a i.putExtra() on it?

Comment: @ChuckNorris Because i have two different activity to launch. I don't want to use those data at next `Intent`. I have to call from other activity.

Answer (score 2):

Um, well don't do it that way for sure. Instead of throwing it all in `SharedPreferences`, pass those pieces in via your `Intent`. For example, instead of:

```
edit.putString("TITLE", getItem(position).title);
```

you can use

```
i.putExtra("TITLE", getItem(position).title);
```

Then, in your `onCreate()` of your detail activity, use:

```
Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
String title = passedIntent.getStringExtra("TITLE");
```

Comment: I don't want to pass those datas to next Intent. I have to use those datas from other activity class.

Comment: That's what your Intent is *for*. When you do `startActivity(i)`, you're passing that `Intent` to your next `Activity`. In that next `Activity`'s `onCreate()`, you can retrieve that `Intent` and the data that was passed in. You should read up on the `Intent` documentation.

Comment: I have to use those data from two different Intent. That's what i am confusing.

Comment: You can't pass multiple Intents to an Activity. Again, you should read the documentation. Intents are the Android way of passing data between Activities.

Comment: Is there any other ways to pass data to multiple activities ?

Comment: You should ask yourself why you're trying to. You can't have more than one Activity open at a time, so you shouldn't need to. Just pass the same data to each Activity with an Intent.